# JMeter error :Could not instantiate org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am getting the below error in JMeter  log while running via jenkins.
I am using JMeter version 2.11r.

```
The logs are:
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: E:\J-Meter\bin\user.properties 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: E:\J-Meter\bin\system.properties 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.11 r1554548 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_121 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 8.1 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.3 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=E:\J-Meter 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\J-meter 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\J-meter 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.150.246.100 Name: NOD-AF1-lo-D1N FullName: NOD-AF1-lo-D1N.timesgroup.com 
2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2017/09/14 17:00:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2017/09/14 17:00:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2017/09/14 17:00:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2017/09/14 17:00:17 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\keytool' 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file E:\J-Meter\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2017/09/14 17:00:18 WARN  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpSamplerGui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: this is a very old version of JMeter. Try to use something newer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're running JMeter 2.11 with Java 8 as per your log lines:

> 2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.11 r1554548
>
> 2017/09/14 17:00:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_121

JMeter is compatible with Java 8 only since version 2.12, as per:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

See:

> Version 2.12
>
> Now, JMeter 2.12 is compliant with Java 8.
> Anyway, 2.11 is 5 versions away from 3.2, so very old now.

Always use last version of JMeter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I tried with the latest version of JMeter i.e 3.2. But this time I am getting the below error message: Started by user Jenkins Test
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\J-meter
[J-meter] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins3780665126580318041.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\J-meter>E:\Work\JMeter\bin\jmeter.bat  
Error: Unable to access jarfile E:\Work\JMeter\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . . 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Thank you but this is another question. My answer is for your initial question. In SO, you need to open a new question . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some Java developers are a little bit relaxed when it comes to handling edge situations (or they simply don't have enough qualification) as it's evidenced by [JENKINS-37013](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37013) (even [Workspace Whitespace Replacement Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Whitespace+Replacement+Plugin) exists)

I would recommend re-installing your Java, Jenkins and JMeter into folders without spaces and special characters in path and the issue should go away, for example:

```
c:\apps\java
c:\apps\jenkins
c:\apps\jmeter
```

Just in case check out [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for more details.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Now all my paths look like:C:\JMeter, C:\Program Files\Java, C:\Jenkins. I am still getting the error : Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\JMeter\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar. I am using J Meter version 3.2 which doesn't have the \ApacheJMeter.jar in the bin folder. Please suggest.